# Replication and AlwaysOn combination

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, transactional-replication

We have 4 geographic regions where data is getting replicated and expected to be real time

Mountain View(main source of ~160 GB), Atlanta, Netherlands, Singapore

We have 2 set of servers App server and reporting servers for all these 4 geographic regions

We are mainlining 2 different publications from Mountain View(where 70% of them are same articles)

Due to few issues replication broke and we did the initialization which took ~48 hrs  due to different geographic regions and entire business was down for 2 days.

I told them to replicate the articles from the local app servers to report servers so that it will be fast, but they are not ready for this as in case of failure both app and report servers will not work.

I am thinking for the better plan to achieve this .How about implementing HADR along with replication .Please suggest with few better ideas. Will the Always On work better for different geography too ?

Comment: Yes, you can do that but you need to pay special attention to different settings that allow you to do an AG via different subnets. As far as replication performance goes across the WAN, have you checked out this white paper? Is your distributor set in a place where the log reader/writer agents are optimized not to run into the 40k command buffer issue? – Ali Razeghi 16 mins ago   
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd263442(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: Replication only works with finished, completed transactions. AGs work with log blocks that contain unfinished transactions. Would this have any implications on your reporting? Your app won't "see" dirty reads, but they will be there. What is the expected replication time, currently, for data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sync 4 geography regions data in sql server](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/146466/sync-4-geography-regions-data-in-sql-server)

Comment: Let's leave this open and close the other one.